# How to set time synchronization server from command line?

Tags: time, window

I need to set "the name of the synchronization server" and check "enable synchronization" option from the command line (possibly using W32tm.exe). I tried different options, manage to only manually synchronize time once, but not permanently set the server name. Is it possible to set this from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your windows version
"Newer" version accept 
**w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:"my.server.com otherserver.net"**

On older versions use **net time /setsntp:"my.server.com otherserver.net"**

Comment: Windows7. Unfortunately this is not working. This command only once synchronize time from the specified server, but does not overwrite the settings in the w32tm.

Comment: try (after the command above) w32tm /config /update --- net stop w32tm -- net start w32tm .---- if this doesn't help check this kb article (it says XP but also works for W7) https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314054

Comment: If I call **net stop W32Time** and **net start W32Time** the time's synchronized with command line server, but the server configured in time dialog remains original, without change. Even after restarting the computer. So I guess the next automatic time synchronization would be conducted by a server configured in the time dialog.

Comment: And in registry [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\W32Time\Parameters] is new server in key "NtpServer"="time.nist.gov", but in time dialog remains original server time.microsoft.com ... :(